# Not getting JQuery/JavaScript object value in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building some UI page using jQuery. In some function, i am creating a JavaScript object as

```
                var key = "04:52:00";
                var val = 13.21;

                var data = {
                    key : val
                };
```

When I try to loop through the `data` object like,

```
              for(var category in data) {
                         alert(category);
                         var points = data[category];
                         alert(points);
              }
```

In the above, I am getting the value of `val` variable correctly as `13.21`, but I am not getting `key` variable value, instead in the `alert(category);`, I am getting `key` not `04:52:00`.

I am not much familiar with jQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use bracket notation to use variables as keys, when using dot notation or when creating an object, the key doesn't have to be quoted, and the literal string will be used as a key instead of the variable.

```
var key = "04:52:00";
var val = 13.21;

var data = {};
data[key] = val;
```

Answer (score 1):

When initializing an object using a literal, like you're doing, you **can't** use variables for keys.

You'll have to use the bracket notation instead:

```
var data = {};
data[key] = val;
```